# Impossible to add a Roo configuration to preferences

Tags: java, spring-roo

I've installed STS 3.8.0 including Spring IDE Roo Support. 
I've installed also ROO 1.3.2 that works fine, even if I've had to add manually the "pref" key in REGEDIT. 
I make an attempt to create a Spring ROO project with the wizard but it require a ROO configuration. By the way the application looped on this and I had to shutdown it via Task Manager. 
I red some hints to use Preferences to add a Roo configuration, simply pointing the %ROO%_home
But I continue to have an error like the image attached. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFNej.gif)
Someone ca help me? 
Thanks
Mirco

Answer (score 2):

As I could see in your provided image https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFNej.gif, you are using `C:\My Project\SpringRoo\bin` folder as Spring Roo folder.

First of all, it's not recommendable to have the Spring Roo distribution inside your project folder because it can affect to the proper behaviour of the shell.

So, your folders should be distributed like these:

- Project to generate: `C:\My Project`
- Spring Roo distribution: `C:\Software\SpringRoo`

On the other hand, you should select a valid Spring Roo folder in the STS configuration. So, following my instructions above, when you select the `Roo home:` you should choose `C:\Software\SpringRoo` folder. As you could see, I don't include `bin` folder.

Hope it helps.

Answer whatever you need to know about the Spring Roo project.

Regards,